# getGraphicalViewer in GEF

Tags: eclipse-gef

I have a GraphicalViewer instance in my GEF application,

which becomes null when called inside a local method.

```
  public FlowChart getModel() 
  { 
      Object topLevelModelElement = null;

      if ( model == null )
      {
      EditPart topLevelEditPart = viewer.getContents();

      topLevelModelElement = topLevelEditPart.getModel();

      model = ( FlowChart )topLevelModelElement;
      }

      return model;
    }
```

A full source code and project is uploadede at

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/643039/

I already inserted

```
configureGraphicalViewer();
initializeGraphicalViewer();
```

where viewer is not null.

Why is the viewer inside getModel() null when called in different method?

Comment: Why are you using the viewer directly? Why not call `getGraphicalViewer()`?

Comment: Dear vainolo, the code above is no more used. Check out the link above. I solved the problem. By the way, while trying to find solution, I frequently visited your website. Thank you.

Comment: @CaliaKim: May I suggest that you add your solution here as an answer for future asnwer-seekers to be found?